# RxJava subscribe onNext is not called when adding element asynchronously

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a Observable like this

```
Observable<String> gitHubRepoModelObservable;
```

I have this code

```
repoNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        gitHubRepoModelObservable = Observable.fromIterable(repoNames);

        repoNames.add("Hello");

        gitHubRepoModelObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

repoNames is just a list of string. When I am adding a string "hello" manually the onNext is getting called but when I am adding string from a API call like bellow

```
 call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubRepoModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubRepoModel>> call, Response<List<GitHubRepoModel>> response) {
                for (GitHubRepoModel repo : response.body()) {
                    repoNames.add(repo.getName());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<GitHubRepoModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

I am adding strings from the API into the repoNames the "onNext" is not getting called.

I have seen

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
```

can be added while initializing retrofit but I want to better understand the rxjava so in this experiment it is not working.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't not be work. 
When you create you api request and try subscribe you list is emty, so Observable does not work. 
You need to create Observable such, that your subcribe will run your request!

```
  Observable<String> gitHubRepoModelObservable = Observable.create(
                    new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void call(final Subscriber<? super String> sub) {

                            call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GitHubRepoModel>>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<List<GitHubRepoModel>> call, Response<List<GitHubRepoModel>> response) {

                                    for (GitHubRepoModel repo : response.body()) {

                                        sub.onNext(repo.getName()); //send result to rx
                                    }
                                    sub.onCompleted();
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<List<GitHubRepoModel>> call, Throwable t) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
            );


gitHubRepoModelObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }


                });
```

Comment: Perfect! Let me get back to you after running it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would `onNext` get called if you are just adding element to plain List?
In the first example you are seeing `onNext` being called because modified list is passed through the stream during `subscribe`. 
Create `Subject` ex. `PublishSubject` and pass list to `Subject.onNext` in `onResponse`, subscribe to it and you will get what you want.

Second option is adding `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` and return `Observable<Response<List<GithubRepoModel>>>`. This way you don't need to create stream yourself.

Comment: Sure things! Now I made some more experiments and things are getting cleared now.